# want to get data in variable using laravel from javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, geolocation

I get the location from user using javascript but i can not get took that data in laravel using variable.

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}

window.onload = getLocation();

</script>
```

i can view this data but i want to get this data using variable.

```
$variabel="<script>document.getElementById("demo")</script>"
```

i tired this way but could not get it

Comment: I don't think you can do that as the templating engine renders the php code before the dom is created

Comment: then what is the good way to do this? i mean getting location information..??

Comment: @FoisalHossain You may have to send data using ajax

Comment: @FoisalHossain where are you trying to get the location? In your server or somewhere else in the same web page?

Comment: @RifatBinReza in the same webpage for calculating distance

Comment: is there any option available in php or laravel to get the exact location using gps without using ip address

Comment: @FoisalHossain you can do that with JavaScript. Because the coordination is collected after the page is loaded, if you want to do something about it in PHP, you should send it to the backend server to process.